# How Do Android Blocking Apps work?

Tags: android

I really need some help. I have an annoying housemate who seems to have downloaded some app that blocks my wifi with a flick of a switch.

Can anyone tell me how I can bypass this, as it's really getting annoying him keep blocking my wifi just as easy as that.

Comment: mostly mac address

Comment: Are all of your devices blocked from connecting? He might using an app which connects to wifi administrator settings by using default username and password and then blocking connected devices.

Comment: is your housemate the owner/administrator of the wifi device?

Comment: MAD-theory would have you cutting the cord between the router and the broadband next time your house-mate blocks your wifi ... you might need to keep doing this 'til the reserve of WAN cords reaches low single digits